# integral $\int e^{C/\sin^2( \theta)}\ d \theta$

Tags: integration

For a simulation (implying Brownian motion) I have to solve :
$$\int e^{C/\sin^2(\theta)}d\theta$$
I did some tries but I failed (I'm not very good with integrals), and Mathematica gave up. Some clues?

Thanks a lot

Comment: If Mathematica cannot find a closed form, I doubt there is a "simple" solution.

Comment: Mathematica is not the God of mathematics, i have found two Errors in calculations

Comment: Try eg https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration

Comment: Hi, thanks for the responses. The point is that I need to express this function in function to C (which is a temporal variable) for further calculation. So I have to resolve it to do so.